# babel obj symbol.iterator undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a `node` project using `ES6`, and using babel cli to compile to `ES5`, but got error on `ES6 for of`

```
let parseParams = (obj)=> {
  let string = ''
  for (var [key,value] of obj) {
    string += `/${key}/${value}`
  }
  console.log(`obj: ${string}`)
  return string;
}
```

compiled js =>

```
for (var _iterator = params[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var _step$value = _slicedToArray(_step.value, 2);

        var key = _step$value[0];
        var value = _step$value[1];

        string += '/' + key + '/' + value;
    }
```

And `params[Symbol.iterator]` is **undefined**

```
let params = {
    key: 'value'
}


babel server.babel.js -o server.js
```

How can I fix this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [*Difference between for...of and for...in*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> The *for...of* syntax is specific to **collections**, rather than all objects. It will iterate in this manner over any the elements of any collection that has a *[Symbol.iterator]* property.

`params` doesn't have a `[Symbol.iterator]` property, therefore you can't use the `for ... of` loop here.

Convert `obj` to an iterable type (such as [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map))

```
let params = new Map([['key', 'value']]);
```

**or** use the `for ... in` loop:

```
for (let prop in obj) {
   string += `/${prop}/${obj[prop]}`
}
```

Comment: I really missing the `set` and `map`. Thanks very much